# Math.Pow(10,1.946) returns 0

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am using the following code:

```
float test = (float)Math.Pow(10,1.946);
```

The problem is that this code returns `0` instead of `88.30799004`. 
Also when using the following code, it will return `0`:

```
double test = Math.Pow(10,1.946);
```

I am using Xamarin and I have set a breakpoint at the variable. With the exact same code it does go off, but returns `0`, why is this?

Comment: Just a control question, when the debugger hit the breakpoint, you did step over the statement, right?

Comment: Also, have you verified this only by inspecting the variable through the debugger, or have you used other means to verify it, such as printing it to debug output, or console output, or some such? The debugger is sometimes confused, and even more so if it is debugging a Xamarin app live on the device, I've experienced loss of variable content when inspecting the variables using the debugger. Please explain exactly how you verified the wrong output.

Comment: Math.Pow receives and retursn a double. Casting it to float may plain loose you any digits. That does not explain the 2nd one, of course.

Comment: @Christopher While that is true, that is relatively irrelevant for this question, as he wouldn't lose *that* much precision.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Didn't use `Debug.Write()` and stepped over the breakpoint: it stayed `0`. When I added `Debug.Write()` and stepped over the breakpoint, it did return the right value `88.30799004`. That's kinda weird?

Comment: ~88.30799 vs. ~88.3079900418563 I would assume he is seeing the *default* value of a float/double.

Comment: @JipHarthoorn Are you sure it actually returned 0 at all? Did the 0 propagate to something where it gave you wildly incorrect results? I'm just making sure that you observed the wrong result through other means than the debugger.

Comment: @JipHarthoorn: Of course, it was the JiT! Without the output, that code is detected as "dead code" and largely skipped. It can be a problem. I once had issues running into a OOM because it was cutting out my "sure to fail" code. Until I gave a output.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Hmm.. I don't exactly understand what you mean with "Did the 0 propagate to something where it gave you wildly incorrect results?" However, I've set a breakpoint to the variable and a variable that came after that and Xamarin showed me that the first variable (test) was 9.

Comment: @Christopher I've never heard of JiT, but I guess you're right haha.

Comment: `was 9` 9? Not 0?

Comment: @mjwills Sorry I meant `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Didn't use Debug.Write() and stepped over the breakpoint: it stayed 0. When I added Debug.Write() and stepped over the breakpoint, it did return the right value 88.30799004. That's kinda weird?"

Not as wierd as you think. One job of the "Just in Time" compiler or [JiT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) is it to cut out dead code. While usually the routines are turned to "very little optimisation" during debug builds, some is still there. I once made this code to force the Runtime to run into the "2 GiB" limit. And nothing happened untill I actually added a output:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace OOM_32_forced
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //each short is 2 byte big, Int32.MaxValue is 2^31.
            //So this will require a bit above 2^32 byte, or 2 GiB
            short[] Array = new short[Int32.MaxValue];

            /*need to actually access that array
            Otherwise JIT compiler and optimisations will just skip
            the array definition and creation */
            foreach (short value in Array)
                Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that usually it is a quite nice and well working part. But with minimalistic test examples it is prone to cause such issues, unfortunately.